# Insert Youtube link if link exists in R

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have this tibble:

```
structure(list(stem = "In what place was Christmas once illegal?", 
    img_vid = "Enter Link", correct = "Russia", d1 = "Brazil", 
    d2 = "England", d3 = "France", exp = "Enter Explanation", 
    exp_img_vid = "Enter Link"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = list(stem = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), img_vid = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), correct = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), d1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), d2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), d3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), exp = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), exp_img_vid = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), class = "col_spec"))
```

I'd like to embed a Youtube video inside a RMarkdown if the link for the video exists in the columns `img_vid` and `exp_img_vid` .

I was thinking of using `if` statements, but how would I do so if the syntax for embedding links is
`![Video Title](Video Link)`

Thanks,

Comment: You can try to construct require character string first  and then use htmltools::HTML function

Comment: Okay, i get the part about using htmltoos::HTML function. How do you "construct require character strings?"